# Access Liferay Custom Field from Velocity template

Tags: liferay, velocity, liferay-6

I'm trying to emit the value of a custom field from within one of the Liferay templates.

Using the admin UI, I have defined a new Organization-level custom field named "org-home-page", with a default value of "tom rules".

I would like to emit this value in portal_normal.vm

I've cobbled this code together based on some posts and samples sent by a co-worker, along with a ton of my own experimentation:

```
$page.getGroup().getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("org-home-page")
```

Unfortunately, Velocity can't resolve the expression, and leaves it untouched.

The following expressions *do* evaluate within portal_normal, but obviously none of these statements does the whole job:

```
$page                               ## seems to represent the current page
$page.getGroup()                    ## seems to represent the current Org
$page.getGroup().getExpandoBridge() ## seems to give me an "Expando bridge" object
```

Only the very last step -- where I identify by name the specific custom field whose value I'd like to retrieve -- is failing.

I'm not allowed to write any custom Java to facilitate this, so don't bother firing up Eclipse. 8) Only solutions that can be implemented entirely within Velocity templates are acceptable.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the value of custom field of an organization using the following approach in Liferay Portal 6.1.0. Maybe it's too verbose but at least it works. :)

#### init_custom.vm

```
...
## Null variable
#set($null = $some-never-used-variable-name)
...
#set($organization = $null)
#if ($layout.getGroup().isOrganization())
    ## Get organization by id
    #set($organizationLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.OrganizationLocalService"))
    #set($organizationId = $layout.getGroup().getOrganizationId())
    #set($organization = $organizationLocalService.getOrganization($organizationId))
#end
...
```

#### portal_normal.vm

```
...
#if ($organization != $null)
    ## Use value of custom field of organization
    $organization.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("org-home-page")
#end    
...
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks. I'm curious about the isOrg check -- is it possible for the current group to NOT be an org? Also -- is there a way to traverse from $layout outward to the current org without doing the lookup via the orglocalservice? Either way, this is excellent as-is.

Comment: @Tom Of course, it's possible for a group not to be an organization group. For example, for site not inside an organization (community) or for an user's pages `$layout.getGroup().isOrganization() == false`. As for getting an organization object, I'm also curious whether it's possible to get it directly from $layout, but unfortunately I didn't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me in Liferay 7+:

Create a custom field type "site", fill data into site settings, and use into theme template for call this data into liferay theme:

If a VM file:

```
#set ($site_custom_field = $layout.getGroup().getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("site_custom_field_key"))
<h1>$site_custom_field</h1>
```

If a FTL file:

```
<#assign site_custom_field = layout.getGroup().getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("site_custom_field_key")>
<h1>${site_custom_field}</h1>
```

Comment: I no longer work in a Liferay environment, so I can't say whether this works. Future researchers are of course welcome to upvote this answer if it works for them. It's also possible this solution only works in newer version of Liferay (my original question is ~5 years old now).